# How can I show the remainder of this Taylor polynomial $R(h)/h^2$ goes to $0$ as $h$ goes to $0$?

Tags: proof-verification, taylor-expansion

Given the function $f(x, y) = \frac 1{2 - x - y^2}$ I found that the second-degree Taylor polynomial is

$$P(x, y) =\frac12 + \frac{x}4 + \frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{y^2}2.$$

How can I show the remainder $R(x, y) = f(x, y) - P(x, y)$ has the property that $$\lim_{h→0}\frac{ R(h)}{|h|^2}= 0,$$ where $h = (h_1, h_2)$.

So I have $$\lim_{h→0}\frac{R(h)}{|h|^2} =$$ $$\lim_{h→0}\frac{-h_1^3 - h_1^2h_2^2 + h_1^2 -2h_1h_2^2 - h_2^4}{4(h_1 + h_2^2 - 2)}\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2} =$$
$$\lim_{r→0}\frac{-r^3\cos^3(θ) -r^4\sin^2(θ)\cos^2(θ) + r^2\cos^2(θ) - 2r^3\cos(θ)\sin^2(θ) - r^4\sin^4(θ)}{r^2(4r\cos(θ) + 4r^2\sin^2(θ) - 8)}=$$ $$ lim_{r→0} \frac{-rcos^3(θ) -r^2sin^2(θ)cos^2(θ) + cos^2(θ) - 2r\cos(θ)\sin^2(θ) - r^2\sin^4(θ)}{4r\cos(θ) + 4r^2\sin^2(θ) - 8} =$$ $$\frac{\cos^2(θ)}{-8}.$$

But this is not equal to 0 so I don't know what I've done wrong

Comment: I believe you mean $|h|^2 = h_1^2 + h_2^2$ at the denominator (instead of $h^2$). As for the question, have you tried writing out the expression for the limit?

Answer (score 0):

Is seems the following.

You wrongly found $P(x,y)$, because

$$f(x, y) = \frac 1{2 - x - y^2}=\frac12 \frac 1{1 - \frac x2 -\frac{y^2}2}=$$
$$\frac 12\left(1+ \frac x2 + \frac{y^2}2+\left(\frac x2 + \frac{y^2}2\right)^2\right)=$$
$$\frac 12\left(1+ \frac x2 + \frac{y^2}2+ \frac{x^2}4 + \dots \right)$$